# Link IEEE Xplore article with its arXiv version in Google Scholar

Tags: arxiv, ieee, google-scholar

After submitting a paper, I uploaded it on arXiv, to give it immediate visibility. 
After a few months (*more than six months*), the article has been accepted and finally published on IEEE Xplore. However, Google Scholar only shows the arXiv version, without pointing to the IEEE one.

How can I manually make Scholar recognize the presence of the published paper?

Comment: Not a verified solution but it probably helps: on arXiv the function "Journal ref" allows you to add a DOI or similar qualifier (once available) to your pre-print to associate it with the actual publication. This probably helps Google with the association; and it's anyway a good thing to do for completeness (and possibly copyright).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google Scholar will eventually find the IEEE version of the paper. Just give it some time.

See the last item of the ["coverage" page of the Google scholar FAQ](https://scholar.google.com/scholar/help.html#coverage) and the second item of the ["search tips" page](https://scholar.google.com/scholar/help.html#corrections).

Comment: It's almost 6 months that the IEEE version isn't indexed in Scholar. Is it normal?

Comment: What has been 6 months? Has it taken 6 months for the article to be published on IEEE Xplore, or has it been published on IEEE Xplore for 6 months and has google still not found it?

Comment: The second one. It's almost six months that the article has appeared in IEEE Xplore, but still Scholar couldn't find it.

Comment: I agree with this answer. It sometimes takes up to a year for records in Google Scholar to update. I've checked that other papers presented at the same workshop are available from IEEE Xplore, which means Google Scholar is aware of the workshop. Chances are the record for your paper will reflect the IEEE Xplore version when they roll out the next major update (as it says in the FAQ, they do this roughly once a year). This issue is sometimes referred to as "Google Scholar preprint bug" http://serialmentor.com/blog/2014/11/1/the-google-scholar-preprint-bug

Answer (score 0):

In such a case the best way to make Google scholar give more intention to your paper is by adding it manually using My Citation (scholar.google.com/citations) section in your Goole scholar account (you can create one if you don't have using your institution email).

Press on Add button.
[image: press on add button]

Click on "Add article manually". Fill the form and press Save.

[image]

After you add the paper details successfully, wait for about month until Google index your work.

Can I know if your IEEE paper appears in Google.com?

Comment: No, it does not appear on Google.com. Only its arXiv version shows up. Do you know why?

Comment: Can you mention your paper title?

Comment: Actually I have almost four papers experiencing the same issue (both published in arXiv and Xplore but not correctly indexed by Scholar). One is, for example, _Multi-Connectivity in 5G mmWave Cellular Networks_.

Comment: if you search using ("Multi-connectivity in 5G mmWave cellular networks" IEEE) you will find your paper was indexed by google. However, I think it does not appear on google scholar because Google alg find arXiv version is better because it has a full text, unlike IEEE that has abstract only.

Comment: Can I know why you are worried about the unavailability of IEEE version on Google scholar? The citation will go to you form any version

Comment: Unfortunately not. As I asked in another question (http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/79859/new-references-of-a-second-version-arxiv-paper-dont-added-in-google-scholar) Scholar is not able to retrieve all the new references added in a _second version_ arXiv paper. If it were able to point to the IEEE version, it would recognize the missing references.

Comment: Try to add manually as mention in my answer. Maybe after mention IEEE journal in "Publisher" field it becomes recognized.

Comment: Whatever you do manually only changes the way you personal GS page looks like. So that is not a solution for the question

Comment: @mgiordi The paper "Multi-connectivity in 5G mmWave cellular networks" still points to the arXiv version. This worries me too. I use Google Scholar button to do referencing. The problem is that if there are others like me if IEEE version does not come up then I might lose important citation count for my paper. The OP could be worried about the same problem.