# References of an updated version arXiv paper not added in Google Scholar

Tags: citations, arxiv, google-scholar

I first uploaded a paper to arXiv and it was correctly added to my Google Scholar profile.
After a few months, I made some modifications to the article, uploading a second version to arXiv (this revised version included some new references too).

However Google Scholar, despite correctly pointing to the (revised) second version of the arXiv paper, did not recognize the new references and so it did not incremented the "citation counter" of the respective papers.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Maybe this is just another variant of the preprint bug? http://serialmentor.com/blog/2015/10/8/Google-Scholar-bug-redux - if so, things may update, but it might take a month.

Comment: I don't know, it's almost five months that I'm having this issue :(

Comment: Have you resolved this issue? I'm having the same problem!

Comment: Has it been solved? I also have the same issue.

Comment: It's possible that these are only re-counted during their 2x a year rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask Google Scholar to merge the two entries! Select both in your profile and then the "MERGE" action at the top, which is initially greyed out, will become active. Click on that and you are done.

If the older entry does not show up in Google Scholar, you can re-add it manually using its arXiv URL. Click on the + sign at the top of you article list and then "Add article manually." Then you can merge.

I guess Scholar might not recognize that two different arXiv URLs relate to the same paper.