# Arxiv updated references not tracked by Google scholar

Tags: citations, arxiv, google-scholar

I uploaded a preprint to arxiv and then uploaded a second version after 2 weeks with additional references. It seems that it has been more than a month but Google Scholar is unable to track the updated references and change the citation count. Has anybody experienced something similar and has solutions to address the problem ?

Comment: Have you asked Google Scholar?

Comment: Seems like you need to wait a bit longer, especially if Google Scholar doesn't include the second version. (You can search for it to find out.)

Comment: Duplicate, but no answer there: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/79859/references-of-an-updated-version-arxiv-paper-not-added-in-google-scholar?rq=1